# Take a one-dimensional range as argument in today's VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a user-defined function in VBA that used to work in older versions of Excel; `=ArrayUnique(A5:A20)` in a cell returned a one-dimensional array containing only unique elements:

```
Function ArrayUnique(ByRef aArrayIn() As Variant) As Variant
    Dim aArrayOut() As Variant, bFlag As Boolean, vIn As Variant, vOut As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    ReDim aArrayOut(LBound(aArrayIn) To UBound(aArrayIn))
    i = LBound(aArrayIn)
    j = i

    For Each vIn In aArrayIn
        For k = j To i - 1
            If vIn = aArrayOut(k) Then bFlag = True: Exit For
        Next
        If Not bFlag Then aArrayOut(i) = vIn: i = i + 1
        bFlag = False
    Next

    If i <> UBound(aArrayIn) Then ReDim Preserve aArrayOut(LBound(aArrayIn) To i - 1)
    ArrayUnique = aArrayOut
End Function
```

I try to run the same function in Excel `Version 2012 (Build 13510.20004)`, it does not work anymore; it returns `#VALUE!`. Debugging it is not easy, because I realise that there is a caching; modify the code does not reflect immediately to the result, I need to change function name to refresh.

Does anyone know 1) how to disable this caching? 2) how to take a one-dimensional range as argument in the most recent version of VBA?

Comment: The oldest Excel version I have at hand is 2003. This code already returns `#VALUE!` in it. Excel has always returned a 2D array for a multicell range. There is no VBA caching either, the changes are reflected immediately. If you don't see your sheet formulas recalculate when you change your code, then yes, that happens, but not because there is code caching, rather, because Excel sees no need to recalculate a function because its arguments have not changed. To make it recalculate, re-enter the formula in just one cell.

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of Excel Range actually returns a two-dimensional array so you need to convert it to a one-dimensional array first. Something like this:

```
Function ArrayUnique(ByVal MyRange As Excel.Range) As Variant
    Dim aArrayOut() As Variant, bFlag As Boolean, vIn As Variant, vOut As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, aArrayIn As Variant
    
    aArrayIn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(MyRange)
    
    ReDim aArrayOut(LBound(aArrayIn) To UBound(aArrayIn))
    i = LBound(aArrayIn)
    j = i

    For Each vIn In aArrayIn
        For k = j To i - 1
            If vIn = aArrayOut(k) Then bFlag = True: Exit For
        Next
        If Not bFlag Then aArrayOut(i) = vIn: i = i + 1
        bFlag = False
    Next

    If i <> UBound(aArrayIn) Then ReDim Preserve aArrayOut(LBound(aArrayIn) To i - 1)
    ArrayUnique = aArrayOut
End Function
```

Usage:

```
?Join(ArrayUnique(Range("A:A")), ",")
```

Comment: `In recent versions of Excel` - `Range` has always returned a 2D array for a multicell range and a single value for a single cell range.

Comment: @GSerg idk but SoftTimur claims that this function once worked.